# javascript function in ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater in an ASP.NET UpdatePanel as follows;

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="rptGalleries" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptAddPhotoGalleries" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                 <input type="checkbox" id="chkNews" data-newsid='<%# Eval("NewsID") %>' runat="server" onclick="javascript:markNews($(this).data('newsid'));" />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
</ContentTemplate>
```

And I use the following javascript within the  element of the HTML;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function markNews(nID) {
          var $span = $('span[data-newsid="' + nID + '"]')
          $span.hide('slow');
        }
    });
</script>
```

when I click on the resulting checkbox, I get an error in the console as follows;

```
ReferenceError: markNews is not defined
javascript:markNews($(this).data('newsid'));
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define your function outside like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FHz7e/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function markNews(nID) {
        var $span = $('span[data-newsid="' + nID + '"]');
        $span.hide('slow');
    }
</script>
```

The jQuery `$(document).ready(function () {` defines an inner scope, so your function is only accessible inside.

---

An alternative would be writing an extension:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.markNews = function (nID) {
        var $span = $('span[data-newsid="' + nID + '"]');
        $span.hide('slow');
    }
});
```

You can call that function directly on the element like in

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkNews" data-newsid='1' runat="server"
       onclick="javascript:$(this).markNews($(this).data('newsid'));" />
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/m72Gs/)

---

With that said, this could even be improved by reading the id inside the function ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m72Gs/1/)):

```
$.fn.markNews = function () {
    var nID = $(this).data('newsid'),
        $span = $('span[data-newsid="' + nID + '"]');
    $span.hide('slow');
}
```

---

#### My suggestion for a final solution

To avoid unnecessary code, I would use the function in outer (global) scope and call it within a jQuery event:

```
function markNews() {
    var nID = $(this).data('newsid'),
        $span = $('span[data-newsid="' + nID + '"]');
    $span.hide('slow');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Ctl_rptAddPhotoGalleries > input').on('click', markNews);
});
```

Of course `#Ctl_rptAddPhotoGalleries` has to be replaced with the rendered id (e.g. `'#<%=rptAddPhotoGalleries.ClientID%> > input'`).

With that, your `<input/>`s can be as clean as

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-newsid='<%# Eval("NewsID") %>' runat="server" />
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/m72Gs/3/)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. For anyone having a similar problem who might visit this post in the future, I have chosen the option to define the function outside. I have not tried writing the extension, but it gave me a great idea on how to create extensions for more commonly used functions. Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

Because you have your function definition wrapped in the `document ready` event, the html is parsed and rendered before the function is defined.  That is why it gives that error.

You should place it outside of the ready event and anywhere before the element in question that relies on it.

Comment: Thank you @Justin your answer is actually correct but I had to choose the answer that was written first and had examples for future visitors having the same problem. I gave you an upvote though.

Answer (score 0):

The function markNews only existing in the scope of the anonymous function that you pass for ready. Therefore, you can't assign it outside it's scope.

But you don't need to create a named function for this (unless you need to call that function in other places not shown in sample code):

```
$(function(){
    $("#<%=rptAddPhotoGalleries.ClientId %> span").click(function(){
        $(this).hide('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to `input` instead of `span`, because there is **no span tag** in your repeater control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function markNews(nID) {
        var $input = $('input[data-newsid="' + nID + '"]');
        $input.hide('slow');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Nice observation @Win, since I could never able to get inside the function, I never run into this problem. FYI, before I used a standard HTML checkbox with an attribute of runat="server", I had an ASP.NET CheckBox which renders a span around it.

Answer (score 0):

They have already said many times above that it does not work because you wrote it in $(document).ready.

Everyone; He tried to get the data he already had using javascript.

Instead of writing directly; Why are you trying to learn with javascript?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkNews" data-newsid='<%# Eval("NewsID") %>' runat="server" onclick='<%# "markNews(" + Eval("NewsID") + ");" %>' />
```

Isn't it easier to create the onclick function this way?

```
onclick='<%# "markNews(" + Eval("NewsID") + ");" %>'
```